# Running Java/C++ Programs in Sublime (no command prompt): There is one unaddressed issue

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've gone through the questions and the solution proposed works great. It helps us both compile and run programs in Sublime text editor instead of opening the command line prompt every time you need to run a program.

**However, it doesn't work when you have to accept input from the console (Like cin and Scanner(System.in)). How do you fix those?**

Answer (score 0):

Running programs within Sublime Text cannot accept input, regardless of the language they're written in. To interact with your program, you'll have to run it through the shell. The only way around this is if you're using an interpreted language like Python, Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, etc., in which case you can install the [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) package and run your code via an interactive session. Unfortunately, since you're using compiled languages, this is not an option.